# How to place Dictionary definitions higher up in spotlight results

Tags: macos, spotlight, dictionary

I used to use spotlight fairly frequently to quickly look up words in a dictionary.  With Lion, I've noticed that my dictionary results have dropped down much lower in the list of results:

[image]

I'd like to bump up the priority of these results so they show up near the top of the list.  However, looking at the system Spotlight preferences in Lion, I don't see an obvious way to do this:

[image]

How can I make Dictionary.app results show up higher in the list of Spotlight results?

Comment: After much looking, I haven't discovered any way to get either. I've started using LaunchBar for my dictionary lookups, I have another hotkey for it - and it has a "Look up in Dictionary" command that pops up first hit for "loo". You can even make a custom abbreviation so whatever key you want searches the dictionary. It's not what you ask, but perhaps you'll be OK with alternatives if you can't yet bend spotlight to your will.

Comment: I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, but you may find satisfaction with a more robust application launcher. It's as easy as typing `define '...'`. I prefer [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), but [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) is great too.

Comment: Lion supports double-tap 3 fingers action for dictionary lookup. I suppose you're using a Mac Pro and don't use trackpad then?

Comment: Oh ho!  That's nice!

Comment: Why would Apple remove this from the system preferences in Lion? Sometimes they do stuff and it makes no sense! :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally, I found a hack! I wrote a blog post about this which you can find [here](http://liang.eu/mac/howto-move-dictionary-definitions-to-the-top-of-spotlight-results) (in Chinese).

These are the key steps:

1. Open the file with [Xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12):

   ```
   ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist
   ```

   If you do not have this file, change the order *System Preferences → Spotlight*  which will cause the OS to create it.
2. Within the `orderedItems` node, add a Dictionary item as follows:
   [image]
3. Save the `.plist` file.
4. Open *System Preferences → Spotlight*, you will find a blank entry, this is what we had added above. You can drag it like other entries to change the order as you like.
5. You are done! Now type a word in spotlight and see what happened.

[image]

Comment: I don't have  the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist`.

Comment: go to _System Preferences → Spotlight_, try reorder the items, close _System Preferences_, and the file will be  created by the system.

Comment: You are welcome! I grad that I can help. And finally I don't have to use CTRL+Down and UP and UP any more

Comment: I've edited your answer and added the step to restart `Finder`. I had to apply this in order for the change to take affect.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, the answer looks much nicer. But it's not necessary to restart `Finder`, this has nothing to do with `Finder`

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but for me the change did not take affect immediately. We can remove this part again as long as nobody complains. :)

Comment: Here was my experience on 10.7.5: I added it and it didn't take at first like @gentmatt. I went into System Preferences, rearranged an item, and then it took -- but it now shows up in duplicate, once where it originally was and now in the new place. I didn't want it twice, so I decided to set `enabled` to NO. Bad idea apparently, as this disables both of them. I then had to change `enabled` to YES, go back to spotlight and rearrange things again, then I was able to remove the key.

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work in Mavericks 10.9.2. What did the trick was restarting after I saved the plist file.

Comment: Unable to reorder items in system preferences in Mojave. So not sure how to generate the file.

Answer (score 72):

In 10.8+, you can open Spotlight, type in the word to look up, and press ⌘L to jump to the definition within Spotlight. Pressing ⌘D instead of ⌘L opens the definition of the typed word in the Dictionary.app.

Comment: Definitely the best answer possible to this question!

Comment: Still works in El Capitan, where they removed option of sorting results. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. Is there one location where all Spotlight key commands are documented? Apple's official doc only has the most often used ones.

Comment: Great! I've searched for this for months.

Comment: @BallpointBen I've found a small list at [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/200660/learn-how-to-use-os-x’s-spotlight-search-like-a-champ/). One I like a lot is CMD+B to instantly search the web for the entered term in your default browser.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of searching, I don’t have a direct answer to your question. But I have a couple of possible fixes:

1. Find your Dictionary in the `Applications` folder. Drop it in the dock. Highlight a word in whatever application you are working in, and drag and drop it into the Dictionary icon in the dock.
2. Google makes the "[Google Quick Search Box](http://www.google.com/quicksearchbox/)" (QSB) which is a lot like QuickSilver and LaunchBar (more like Quicksilver of the two). I think for your purpose, QSB is the best option. Google will give you Dictionary results quite readily based on some criteria. I found that if the definition was not immediately available, I could invoke it more explicitly by typing the word whose definition I am seeking followed by ‘definition’.

Here is a little more information about those ‘quick launch’ applications. Google’s QSB is free, quite capable, clean in appearance, but is a little sluggish. … LaunchBar is faster, pretty powerful, not as ‘pretty’, and costs around USD 25-40. Quicksilver has been discontinued, and the developer has recommended that users switch to LaunchBar.

Comment: Quicksilver available again, and is recently out of beta.  http://qsapp.com

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Thank you. That's good to know. I will be recommending it to others. (As a matter of fact I just recommended it to a friend by email.)