# Is it possible to remove Web Searches from Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, search, plist

when I am searching anything with spotlight a category *Web Searches* appears at the bottom of the results. Clicking these links Safari opens and would search the web or wikipedia. But I never use these web searches and I would like to remove them.

Removing *Webpages* from the spotlight system preferences did not help.

I found several instructions on removing [*Developer*](https://superuser.com/questions/322533/why-is-spotlight-indexing-documents-although-i-disabled-documents-indexing) and [*Others*](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23635962#23635962), or to rate the [dictionary results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22897/how-to-place-dictionary-definitions-higher-up-in-spotlight-results/) up.

All these make use of `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spotlight.plist`.

Maybe it is possible using this file, but I was not able to find out the proper value for the *name* key in order to remove the *Web Searches* category. Or maybe there is another solution to this problem?

Any suggestions? I am using OS X Mavericks 10.9.3, btw.