# How to hide files found in spotlight?

Tags: macos, spotlight

[image]

I want to hide **TOP HIT**, **FOLDERS** and **DEVELOPER** catalogues. The only item I expect is **DEFINITION**. Is there any way to do this? Here is my current preference, but it doesn't work.

[image]

[This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/22897/168383) can't solve my question, because

1. I haven't installed Xcode, and I don't want to install such a huge application on my 128G MBA.
2. I don't want to search files on my disk at all.

Comment: Small note for the future: you don't need to use Xcode to edit .plist files: you can edit them as plain text and they'll still work, the only difference is that Xcode adds protections and makes it look pretty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal, and execute

```
touch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

A zero-sized file named `Xcode.app` will be created under that path. Now you are able to see and hide the DEVELOPER catalogue in **System Preferences** -> **Spotlight**. Just like this:

[image]