# Why are my Spotlight results so awful?

Tags: macos, spotlight, monterey, dictionary

I use spotlight extremely frequently for looking up word definitions.

Sometimes I have noticed that I don't get the word's definition back at all. For example, just now I looked up "express".

I'm hoping to see the Oxford English Dictionary definition for "express".

Instead I got these results:

[image]

How can I make Spotlight actually just show me the dictionary definition of what I've typed?

Ideally I would also like to disable all the results that appear above the dictionary entry. I'm never interested in any of that Safari stuff. (Is it all even Safari?)

Comment: Not sure about how you can set the appearance order of categories but you can set the categories to appear in your Spotlight searches through System Preferences > Spotlight > Search Results.

Comment: @Alper the only categories enabled according to that are: Applications, Calculator, Conversion, Definition. I don't see how I could get rid of the Safari stuff.

Comment: 1) The Command-space interface to Spotlight is getting worse. The first result I get for "express" is an app (which I have never used) with "express" in its name.  I am expecting to see an increasing range of adverts over the next year to two. 2) For a word definition I use either "Look Up" from control-click connect menu or PopClip.

Comment: Have you read https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22897/how-to-place-dictionary-definitions-higher-up-in-spotlight-results? I am not sure if the answer still works as I think Spotlight now changes the order based on your usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitions are derived in order of preferences set in Dictionary app. By default, Apple Dictionary is before Oxford dictionaries.

In order to get a Oxford English Dictionary (or any other dictionary you prefer) definition:

Go to the Dictionary app preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>): in the opening window, there is "Drag reference sources into the order you prefer"; reorder dictionaries as you like and tick/untick as needed.

In Spotlight, write 'express'; then, use the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the definition from your most preferred dictionary in Spotlight window or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open it in the Dictionary app.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you stop using Spotlight for this purpose. To get more control over searching change to using [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com).

Alfred is a very configurable search tool, usually initiated with `option-space`.

By default (and you can change it) dictionary definitions are shown with the keyword 'define'. After `option-space`, just type "define express".

[image: Alfred define]

Select (up-down keys and return) "express" in show it in the Dictionary app.